# How Can I Make this Code More Efficient i.e. to one or two lines?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
census_df = census_df.loc[((census_df['REGION'] >= 1) & (census_df['REGION'] <=2))]
census_df = census_df[census_df['CTYNAME'].str.match('Washington')]
census_df = census_df[census_df['POPESTIMATE2015'] > census_df['POPESTIMATE2014']]
census_df = census_df[['STNAME', 'CTYNAME']]
census_df
```

I know that there must be a way that I can condense this to one line of code using . Would I just use the "&" symbol to connect the first three lines?

Comment: How expensive are the lines of your sourcefile? Why is shorter more efficient? What about readaility/communication of intent of your code and maintainability?

Comment: Combining logic into one line does **not** make it more efficient. Most of the computational time will be in creating Boolean arrays, *not* in applying them to your dataframe. If you are *really* concerned about one-lining an answer, calling your dataframe `df` instead of `census_df` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'query()' could save you lots of spaces.

```
census_df = census_df.query("                       \
                (1 <= REGION <= 2)                  \
              &  CTYNAME.str.match('Washington')    \ 
              & (POPESTIMATE2015 > POPESTIMATE2014)
          ")[['STNAME', 'CTYNAME']]
```

In one line:

```
census_df = census_df.query("(1 <= REGION <= 2) & CTYNAME.str.match('Washington') & (POPESTIMATE2015 > POPESTIMATE2014)")[['STNAME', 'CTYNAME']]
```